# not working fuzzy logic when use the fuzzines.auto elasticsearch

Tags: c#, .net, api, elasticsearch, fuzzy-search

I want it to return similar results when a word is typed in the search box, even if the word is wrong. For example, when I type "gpple" it should come up with "google". I use Fuzzines.Auto for this but it doesn't work. I am attaching the code I wrote, I would appreciate if you could help. thanks

[image]

Comment: please use text instead of screenshot when possible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the doc [QueryString query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-query-string-query.html#query-string-fuzziness) you must use fuzzy like this (adding operator ~ in the end term:

```
{
  "query": {
    "query_string": {
      "fields": ["fields_name"], 
      "query": "searchtext~"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: thenk u @rabbitbr. its work! you are great :)